# Ошибка Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

При добавление записи в бд возникает ошибка, может кто-нибудь помочь её исправить?
"Ошибка Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
 
// экранирования символов для mysql
$licscore = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['licscore']));
$field_0 = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field_0']));
 
// создание строки запроса
$query ="INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(NULL, '$licscore','$field_0')";
 
// выполняем запрос
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
if($result)
{
    echo "<span style='color:blue;'>Данные добавлены</span>";
}
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);
```

}
?>

Comment: Желательно так.
`INSERT INTO <tablename> (field1, field2, field3, ... fieldN) VALUES(value1, value2, value3, ... valueN)` 
Но, если Вы используете короткий синтаксис (с опусканием перечисления названия полей) - в таком случае будьте добры перечислить кол-во значений равное кол-ву полей. Т. е если у Вас в таблице 5 полей то и значений укажите 5. Если же Вам необходимо заполнить значениями конкретные поля - тогда см. первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что вопрос совсем не про это, но в этом коде неверно примерно всё. Буквально каждая строчка неверная или лишняя.

Самое главное, **никакого "экранирования" символов для mysql в природе не существует**. Это детсадовские сказки, которые, к сожалению, никак не вывести из похапешной тусовки
Поэтому надо выполнять **подготовленные запросы** вместо этого колупания с "escape"

```
<?php
// подключаемся к серверу
// выдавать ошибки автоматом, а не бегать за каждым запросом с die mysqli_error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database); 
// выставляем кодировку, чтобы не бегать потом с вопросами "откуда у меня кракозябры??"
$link->set_charset("utf8mb4");

// создание строки запроса
$query ="INSERT INTO test1 (licscore, field_0) VALUES(?,?)";
// подготавливаем запрос
$stmt =  $link->prepare($query); 
// привязываем к нему переменные
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['licscore'], $_POST['field_0']); 
//выполняем запрос
$stmt->execute();

// после успешного POST запроса ВСЕГДА должен быть редирект
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

**Всё**, больше в коде ничего не нужно.
Получается, короче, безопаснее, и гораздо осмысленнее

И да, выполняя запрос на вставку, всегда явно надо перечислять те поля, которые мы вставляем.

Comment: так выдает ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_charset() on null

Comment: Это просто опечатка, мог бы и сам исправить

Comment: а что означают вопросительные знаки после VALUES?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/148701/

Comment: у меня появляется такая ошибка "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'score' cannot be null ", но данные в БД записываются, это нормально?

Comment: нет это не нормально. при этой ошибке данные не записываются. что за колонка score? почему в запросе в нее ничего не пишется?

Comment: это самая первая колонка, я ее заполняю и выдает ошибку, но при этом данные записываются

Comment: ну где ты заполняешь если у тебя в вопросе стоит NULL? `"INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(NULL, '$licscore','$field_0')";`. Я еще не совсем оcлеп и вижу здесь NULL в первой колонке

Comment: я все равно не понимаю в чем ошибка, я убрал NULL и вообще вставил твой код, но все равно появляется эта ошибка

Comment: ошибка в том, что надо не убрать это поле, а надоборот добавить. и передавать в него значение. ну или брать NOT NULL из структуры таблицы.